# Add a DataGridViewRow to a BindingSource

Tags: c#, datagridview, c#-2.0, bindingsource

I have two DataGridViews, one with data bind by a BindingSource and the second DataGridView with only one row and is not bind.

In the second DataGridView users can fill in values and via an Add button the values will be Added into the first DataGridView.

But now I don't know how I have to add this new row (record) to the first DataGridView. The best thing to do this, I think is to add this new row to the bindingSource of DataGridView 1?

But how do I have to do this.

Can somebody help me? I need the code in C#
Thx already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very typical that, when you ask an question you don't get answers but only other "why" questions. Mine question was very clear, but why I use this and not that.....

So it cost me some time but finally a find mine own answer, use the folowwing:
where bs = the BindingSource and RowArray the record from the second grid.

```
((DataTable)(bs.DataSource)).Rows.Add(RowArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) with your business objects. As I see in MSDN its supported in .NET v2.0. What you need to do:

```
//Create list of products
BindingList<Product> myList = new BindingList<Product>();
//set datagridview datasource
dataGridView.DataSource = myList;
//add new product, named Cookie, to list ant boom you'll see it in your datagridview
myList.Add(new Product("Cookie"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you set `AllowUserToAddRows = True` and use only one DataGridView? In this case you don't have to take care of adding the row to the DataGridView.

Comment: That is to simple, if that was the case I would have done it that way, but that isn't possible.

Comment: So could you please give a reason for holding data in one GridView and having a second GridView with the same columns and just on row for the only purpose to add a new row???

Comment: The reason I need two grids is that I also use an filter extender, this filter extender creates a lot of extra errors when you use textboxcells and changes them into comboboxes (the well known reentrant bug)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you store your data in an `ObservableCollection<Type>`? Bin d your DataGridView1 to that dictioary. If then in DataGridView2 a new record is added, just simply add a new entry to that ObservableCollection. "By Magic" it will be shown in DataGridView1. "The Magic" is the observable pattern implemented by the ObservableCollection and used by the DataGridView.

Comment: I forgot ot say we use 2.0., so the ObservableCollection isn't available for me.

Comment: So, why don't you switch to current version?

Comment: Because I'm working at an client and the whole application is built in 2.0 and they don't want to switch.